# Jenkins poll scm (SVN) says no changes even though there are

Tags: svn, jenkins

We are using Jenkins 2.8. Also we are using poll scm trigger for most of our jobs and everything seems to be working fine, except for one job.

This specific job is configured to poll scm every 2 minutes, which it does, but always displaying this message:

> Started on 11:40:22 02/11/2016 
>   Received SCM poll call on master for [job name] on 11:40:23 02/11/2016 
>   [url to folder] is at revision 16,860 
>   Done. Took 1.8 sec
>   No changes

It does not detect any changes even when the last build was on revision 16,840.

I found a similar issue in stackoverflow and the solution suggested to sync the clocks between the SVN and Jenkins server, but because the poll SCM works for the rest of our projects for few years now, I don't think that this is the solution.

I compared the configuration on this specific job to the rest that works, and they are same (except for the code folder of course).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Update:
I have committed some code again and now I see this in the poll scm log

> Ignored revision 16,868: Found no included paths

Comment: I would try to delete the job and re-create it... it should not take long, and will most likely fix your issue. Regarding the reason behind, I have no idea, but since your other jobs are working correctly, I bet there is some internal state (svn meta data perhaps?) that makes it behave incorrectly.

Comment: I will try to re-create it, but before that, maybe this information will help: Now I see this message "Ignored revision 16,868: Found no included paths". Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-creating the job fixed the issue.